# Binary tree level order traversal with Queue stuck in infinite loop

Tags: c, algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

I have been trying to implement binary tree with queue in C and I am fairly new to this language. I have been trying to debug the code I have written in C, wrote the code from scratch but with no fruit. I can not see what am I doing wrong.

I checked the queue code that I wrote with integer data and it worked perfectly.

- enqueue function pushes an element in the queue
- dequeue function pops an element from the queue
- empty function check if queue is empty

Then I implemented Binary Search Tree and printed the elements in the node with

```
root -> left -> left -> left -> data; //worked fine, was able to reach the extreme left leaf node
```

and

`root -> right -> right -> right -> data; //worked fine, just in case`

and some more traversals like this and it seems the tree formed fine. I printed the queue in `level_order()` function and what I could understand was queue was not building right. Somehow the whole thing goes into infinite loop. I have ran out of ideas. Here's the code, thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct BstNode{
    int data;
    struct BstNode *left;
    struct BstNode *right;
};

struct Queue{
    struct BstNode *address;
    struct Queue *next;
};

struct Queue *front = NULL;
struct Queue *back = NULL;

struct Queue* create_queue(BstNode **address){
    struct Queue *temp = (Queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
    temp -> next = NULL;
    temp -> address = *address;
    return temp;
}

void enqueue(BstNode **address){
    struct Queue *temp = create_queue(address);
    if(front == NULL && back == NULL){
        front = back = temp;
    }
    else{
        temp -> next = back;
        back = temp;
    }
}

void dequeue(){
    if(front == NULL){
        return;
    }
    struct Queue* temp;
    temp = back;
    if(front == back){
        front = back = NULL;
    }
    else{
        back = back -> next;
    }
    free(temp);
}

bool empty(){
    if(front == NULL){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void print_queue(){
    struct Queue *temp = back;
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%d", temp->address->data);
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

struct BstNode *root;

struct BstNode *create_node(int data){
    struct BstNode *temp = (BstNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct BstNode));
    temp -> data = data;
    temp -> left = NULL;
    temp -> right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

void insert_bst_cell(BstNode **node, int data){
    if((*node) == NULL){
        struct BstNode* temp = create_node(data);
        *node = temp;
    }
    else if(data > (*node)->data){
        insert_bst_cell(&(*node)->right, data);
    }
    else if(data < (*node)->data){
        insert_bst_cell(&(*node)->left, data);
    }
}

BstNode *first_element(){
    return front->address;
}

void level_order(){
    if(root == NULL) return;
    enqueue(&root);
    while(!(empty())){
        struct BstNode *current = first_element();
        dequeue();
        printf("%d\n", current->data);
        if(current->right != NULL){
            enqueue(&(current->left));
        }
        if(current->left != NULL){
            enqueue(&(current->right));
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    front = NULL;
    back = NULL;
    root = NULL;
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 15);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 10);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 20);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 5);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 11);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 17);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 25);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 4);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 6);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 9);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 12);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 16);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 19);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 21);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 35);
    level_order();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [Don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) in C...

Comment: This is more or less C code compiled with a C++ compiler. In other words: it compiles with a C++ compiler but it does not compile with a C compiler. BTW you forgot the `#include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h>
`

Comment: We could really use an accurate problem description: where is the infinite loop, what are the critical variable values there, and what does the tree *really* look like at that point?

Comment: Did you test your queue implementation? I think it's a stack and not a queue. That should not explain the infinite loop though.

Comment: I'll check the queue implementation, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Paul Georg Podlech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4815713/paul-georg-podlech) for pointing it out that I had implemented a stack instead of queue. The other mistake was

```
if(current->right != NULL){
    enqueue(&(current->left));
}
if(current->left != NULL){
    enqueue(&(current->right));
}
```

in this particular code. It should be

```
if(current->left != NULL){    //current -> right in previous snippet
    enqueue(&(current->left));  
}
if(current->right != NULL){    //current -> left in previous snippet
    enqueue(&(current->right));
}
```

And just in case I'll post the working code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct BstNode{
    int data;
    struct BstNode *left;
    struct BstNode *right;
};

struct Queue{
    struct BstNode *address;
    struct Queue *next;
};

struct Queue *front = NULL;
struct Queue *back = NULL;

struct Queue* create_queue(BstNode **address){
    struct Queue *temp = (Queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
    temp -> next = NULL;
    temp -> address = *address;
    return temp;
}

void enqueue(BstNode **address){
    struct Queue *temp = create_queue(address);
    if(front == NULL && back == NULL){
        front = back = temp;
    }
    else{
//        temp -> next = back;
        back -> next = temp;
        back = temp;
    }
}

void dequeue(){
    if(front == NULL){
        return;
    }
    struct Queue* temp;
    temp = front;
    if(front == back){
        front = back = NULL;
    }
    else{
        front = front -> next;
    }
    free(temp);
}

bool empty(){
    if(front == NULL){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void print_queue(){
    struct Queue *temp = back;
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%d", temp->address->data);
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

struct BstNode *root;

struct BstNode *create_node(int data){
    struct BstNode *temp = (BstNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct BstNode));
    temp -> data = data;
    temp -> left = NULL;
    temp -> right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

void insert_bst_cell(BstNode **node, int data){
    if((*node) == NULL){
        struct BstNode* temp = create_node(data);
        *node = temp;
    }
    else if(data > (*node)->data){
        insert_bst_cell(&(*node)->right, data);
    }
    else if(data < (*node)->data){
        insert_bst_cell(&(*node)->left, data);
    }
}

BstNode *first_element(){
    return front->address;
}

void level_order(){
    if(root == NULL) return;
    enqueue(&root);
    while(!(empty())){
        struct BstNode *current = first_element();
        dequeue();
        printf("%d\n", current->data);
        if(current->left != NULL){
            enqueue(&(current->left));
        }
        if(current->right != NULL){
            enqueue(&(current->right));
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    front = NULL;
    back = NULL;
    root = NULL;
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 15);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 10);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 20);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 5);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 11);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 17);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 25);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 4);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 6);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 9);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 12);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 16);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 19);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 21);
    insert_bst_cell(&root, 35);
    level_order();
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you everyone for their valuable time and input.